# REST API and MPL together. Is this possible?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am building an iOS app in which there is a functionality of Profile Sharing and person to person simple payment both.

For Profile Sharing, I am using `PayPal REST API` and have successfully implemented.

For person to person simple payment, I think I will have to use `PayPal MPL` as `PayPal REST API` still does not support person to person simple payment.

But the problem is I am unable to include both the APIs together in my project since both API is provided with payment option and so both API conflicts. Is there any alternate way of achieving this both?

Answer (score 1):

MPL is built on the old Adaptive Payments stack. To work directly with the rest API, you should look at the [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK). However you are correct that person to person payments are not well supported.

Comment: I guess you are the one who has last committed PayPal iOS SDK on GitHub.. :D... so let me ask you..Any idea when REST API will be fully functional?

Comment: What does "fully functional" mean to you? There are a number of features slated for development & release at different times this year. However since the SDKs are just wrappers for the APIs, I have limited knowledge of dates for specific features.

Comment: I meant person to person payment. It is very important feature that is still missing in this iOS SDK. I read somewhere on GitHub in one of the issues that PayPal developers are aggressively trying to get through this functionality. So any updates on that?